# Virtualmin deployment warning on Digital Ocean

Tags: hosting, digital-ocean, virtualmin

I seem to be getting this error on Digital Ocean:

"Your system's primary IP address appears to have changed from xxx.xx.xx.xxx to xx.xx.x.x. Virtual servers using the old address may be unreachable or serve the wrong web content."

This is on a fresh install of virtualmin on digital ocean.

Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: Turns out that the best way to solve this was by making sure the hostname was correct. And a reboot was done on the webmin module once everything was set up.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the best way to solve this was by making sure the hostname was correct. And a reboot was done on the webmin module once everything was set up.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying a custom image on a new droplet, Virtualmin/Webmin on the image notices a new IP address assigned to the droplet. When this happens, on the first login to Virtualmin/Webmin shows above error message on the page -

To fix this error you should change the IP address of your server. Below are the steps on how to change the IP address in Webmin:

How to change the IP address in Webmin

```
Step 1. We logged into Webmin clicked on Networking menu on the left panel.

Step 2. Here we just click on Network Configuration.

Step 3. Then select Network Interfaces for setting up new IP address configuration.

Step 4. Here we click on enp0s3 network interface for new IP address configuration.

(it can be named in many ways, including eth0, enp0s1, ig0 and so on, and your system may have more than one adapter)

Step 5. Now, here we have five changes for new IP address configuration.

->  Select Yes to enable the Network Interface and activated on boot.
->  Select Static Configuration option in the IPV4 address section.
->  After selecting the static configuration, we enter the static IP address on IPV4 Address field.
->  Then enter Subnet Mask on Netmask field (eg: 255.255.255.0).
->  Finally enter the Broadcast address (eg: 192.168.1.255). Most probably Broadcast address is taken by the system automatically.

After all, save the settings.

Step 6. Then, go to Routing and Gateways, select the previously configured interface name from the dropdown and enter the correct Gateway IP address in the field.

Step 7. Click Save and go back to the main screen.

Step 8. Click on Apply Configuration button.

We verified the IP Address of the system just by running the below command.

Linux command: ifconfig
```

If you face any issue to login into your Webmin due to IP change, please follow the below steps to fix that error

```
Step 1. Check the log file /var/log/webmin/miniserv.log to identify the problem. 

Step 2. If the new IP address is not configured in /etc/webmin/miniserv.conf file then we need to add it.

Step 3. Log into Webmin and go to Addresses and Networking -> Change IP Addresses, and there we can change references to the old IP address to the new one.

Step 4. Finally rebooted the server.
```

That’s it, now the problem fixed.